# PHP - Can curl_exec( ) return partial results?

Tags: php, curl

I'm using PHP's built in cURL functions to make some requests and capture the headers (for the specific purpose of displaying headers). It generally works well. I have `curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);` set, so that redirects will be followed and at the end, there will be groups of headers for each HTTP request made, including all redirects.

The problem is that sometimes a redirect will be 'stale' and point to a domain that no longer exists. In this case, `curl_exec( )` throws an error and returns no data.

However in my specific use here, it would be very useful for `curl_exec( )` to return "whatever it's got so far" on error, so I could at least show the headers for all the pages that worked, and you would be able to see where it goes wrong. But I can't find any way to accomplish this.

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Don't follow redirects automatically, store response in a variable, check status and determine if another request is need to be made

Comment: Hmm yup I suppose that is the "hard" way to do it if no easy way exists. It's such an outlier case, I'll have to put that on my longer term to-do list.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could use CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION to get the headers?

```
$received_headers=array();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,function($ch,string $header) use(&$received_headers):int{
    $received_headers[]=$header;
    return strlen($header);
});
curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($received_headers);
```

that said, in this situation, i would be happier with all the debug data provided by CURLOPT_VERBOSE - this doesn't just give you headers, but if there's a connection drop or anything wierd like that, it will tell you, so you have some idea of what happened other than what headers you received. so instead, i would recommend something like:

```
$debug_str='';
$debugfileh=tmpfile();
$debugfile=stream_get_meta_data($debugfileh)['uri'];
curl_setopt_array($ch,array(
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE=>true,
    CURLOPT_STDERR=>$debugfileh
));
curl_exec($ch);
$debug_str=file_get_contents($debugfile);
fclose($debugfileh);
unset($debugfile,$debugfileh);
var_dump($debug_str);
```

note, the solution above would give you the headers, but not the `response body recieved so far`  (if any), to do that, you'd probably have to combine both (CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION or CURLOPT_VERBOSE) and CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION

edit: fixed some bugs in the 2nd code, the original code i wrote would just give curl_setopt some silent errors...